# In what range does caml_hash_varian return values?

Tags: c++, c, hash, ocaml, polymorphic-variants

The subchapter "[20.3.6  Polymorphic variants](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#ss:c-polyvar)" describes how to identify polymorphic variant value in C (*It contains a mistake: should be `caml_hash_variant` instead of `hash_variant`)

I want to use those hash values as error codes in C++ directly. Something like that

**archive.mli:**

```ml
...
type t = ...
type err = [`File_not_found | `Archive_is_corrupted]
val opena : string -> (t, err) error
...
```

**archive.ml**

```ml
...
let () = Callback.register "open archive" opena
...
```

**archive.cpp:**

```cpp
...
const int Error::File_not_found = caml_hash_variant("File_not_found")
const int Error::Archive_is_corrupted = caml_hash_variant("Archive_is_corrupted")

int Archive::open(char* path) {
  static const value* f = nullptr; \
  if (f = nullptr) 
      f = caml_named_value("open archive");

  value result = caml_callback(*f, caml_copy_string(path));
  if (Tag_val(result) == 0) { // Result.Ok
    archive = Field(caml_state, 0);
    return ??????
  } else { // Result.Error
    return Int_val(Field(caml_state, 0));
  }
}
...
```

There is no problem with to return error code and compare it

```cpp
if (x.open(path) == Error::Archive_is_corrupted) {
...
}
```

But I don't know what I can return as **OK** status. **0?** **-1?**
Does any guaranteed value that cannot be returned by `caml_hash_variant` exist?

Comment: I found one idea: return `caml_hash_variant("OK")`. But it is more common to return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediate values in the usual OCaml implementation have the low bit set, and the variant hash is an immediate value. So if you're looking at variant hash values in C++ you can be sure that the value 0 will never be returned by caml_hash_variant.

If you look at the code, the final value is generated either by Val_int() or Val_long(). In the definitions of these macros you'll see that they guarantee that the low bit is set.

I haven't done any kind of analysis of the code, but the value -1 is at least superficially possible as a hash value, since its low bit is set.

**Update**

The low bit is set on immediate values as a marker for the garbage collector. So it's a convention that must be followed strictly. (IMHO it's one of many really nice design tradeoffs in the OCaml implementation.)

Comment: So, there is no **x** for which **caml_hash_variant(x) == 0**?

Comment: Correct. Look at the macro defintions and you'll see why.

Comment: The GC, if it ever gets hold of it, will consider 0 as a pointer. And 0 will be outside any of the heaps the GC controls so it will not follow it. So that will be safe to use. But you will have no valid way to create that value on the ocaml side. You need an `OK hash variant or change err to an option.